# Problem with menu entries .desktop files in Elementary OS 5.1

Tags: slingshot, launcher

I need to create two .desktop files for launching, from the dock or menu, two application that are currently launched from the terminal with ./app-file  and ./app-file.sh commands. I have already created   with success the two .desktop files in an Ubuntu installation simply inserting the application path in the "Exec" key but this method doesn't work in Elementary OS. I tried to use "AppEditor" utility to create the menu entries but inserting the application path in the Exec field but the utility does not recognize the app-file as an executable. How can i solve these problems?

Comment: Please split the 2 issue in two different question, is way easier to help you that way!
Can you please run `ls -alh` on the `app-file` and `app-file.sh` and update your answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Your hint allowed me to understand and solve the problem by updating the file permissions as executable.

Comment: can you answer your question with the solution and later accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the ls -alh command, as suggested in the "endorama" comment, allowed me to understand that app-file and app-file.sh did not have execute permission.
So I changed the permissions by adding the "execute" permission on each file:
right-click-> Properties (context menù)-> "Permissions" (pop-up windows) -> "Execute".

Comment: if this is a multiuser system ... you MAY need to alter permissions on those files again ... in this case you may want the executable flags set for user, group, and other